# JQuery Dialog slower and slower after each open

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a JQuery Dialog that contains some error information, along with an action link 'Details' that toggles a more detailed error explanation.

My problem is that after I open and close the dialog box about six times it gets progressively slower on open and unresponsive. Google chrome will even ask me to kill the process sometimes. I don't understand why, am I using jquery dialog the wrong way?

below is a code example, errorbox div is in the main html page is not shown below. its just an empty div, its contents come from controller which just returns a partial view.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    var dialog = $(".errorbox").dialog({
        title: 'Error',
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: false
    });
    $('.showhidetarget').hide();


    //Open dialog box for errors
    $(".openDialog").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".errorbox").load(this.href);
        dialog.dialog('open');

    });

    //Show details for Error box message
    $('.showhidetrigger').click(
    function () {
        $('.showhidetarget').toggle();
    });

});
```

Razor partial view:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/OpenDialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<p>@Model.friendly_message</p>

<a class ="showhidetrigger" href="#">Details</a>
<div class = "showhidetarget">
   <p>@Model.detailed_message</p>
</div>
```

jquery files included:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/OpenDialog.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

**

### EDIT

**

I found the solution to the problem, but not the reason.

Removing the include to my javascript file OpenDialog from the partial view and moving the toggle for the link into a script tag in the partial view fixes the problem.

So some how including the javascript file in my partial view is causing the problem but I don't know why. the click function is called more and more times. such as first time its just calls the click function once...then second time it calls it twice...then four, then eight and so on. so its contents is being reloaded more and more times. But I don't know why including this in my partial view would cause this to happen...

So I'm leaving this open if someone can tell me why this is causing the problem.

Comment: You dont need bother versions (normal and minified), just use the minified versions

Comment: Are you using this on the master page?

Comment: You're also including jQuery UI before jQuery! Definitely don't do that. It might even be contributing to the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I made those changes, sadly they didn't fix the problem. These are included in the '_Layout' page. I don't have a master page.

Answer (score 0):

The description of [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) reads

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

It does not however say "Replace" anywhere. I can only guess that every time you open the dialog, more data is loaded into it. Try clearing the content from the dialog before you load new data into it:

```
//Open dialog box for errors
$(".openDialog").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Empty the box before loading more content
    $(".errorbox").empty().load(this.href);
    dialog.dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: I just tried this...same result. But check my edit it might change your answer.

Comment: also inspecting the source it does appear to be replacing it. also my script tag isn't even in the source..not sure why...